# Is washing fruits/vegetables with water useful?

Tags: nutrition, environmental-health

[People](http://nutrition.about.com/od/ahealthykitchen/a/washveggies.htm) tend to recommend washing (even just with water) fruits/vegetables before eating them for health reasons.

Do we have evidence that washing fruits/vegetables with water reduce potential health risks?

Comment: You need to define useful.  Washing fruits with water is useful if you prefer to eat wet fruit.  But I doubt that is what you mean.  Please specify what you mean by useful.

Comment: Related: [Do fruit/vegetable washes effectively remove pesticides?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5865)

Answer (score 9):

I expect it depends on how dirty the food is to begin with, and on what type of dirt (just as the answer to [this other question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3253/2703) depends on how dirty the floor is), and also on whether the food is subsequently cooked.

[This FDA page](http://www.fda.gov/food/resourcesforyou/consumers/ucm114299) and [this Health Canada page](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/hl-vs/iyh-vsv/food-aliment/handling-manipulation-eng.php) both recommend washing (using identical text).

However, the FDA site says that that's not effective for sprouts:

> Rinsing sprouts first will not remove bacteria.

One problem (i.e. the reason why washing doesn't always work) is that pathogens can sometimes get inside the produce: for example, see item 3 of [this web page](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/fn-an/securit/kitchen-cuisine/safety-salubrite/research-recherche_microb-eng.php):

> What is the evidence of internalization of pathogens into produce and how significant is this?
>
> - Is it a problem with crops other than tomatoes, apples and potatoes?
> - What are the best prevention methods?
> - Once pathogens infiltrate the product, how long will they survive/grow?
> - Can epidemiologically relevant numbers of pathogenic microorganisms infect a field crop via this route?

The same page lists "What is the efficacy of produce washing at home? (Does water remove pathogens from product?)" as a low-priority research area for them.

Page 43 of [this 2008 WHO document](http://www.who.int/foodsafety/publications/micro/MRA_14_JEMRA.pdf) (on which that previously-mentioned Canadian page was based) says various things including,

> Washing in potable or sanitized water typically results in TVC/ACC reductions of 1–2 logs
> (CCFRA, 1999, 2002). However, the degree of risk reduction that can be expected from these
> current washing disinfection technologies is difficult to quantify in reality (i.e. under non-inoculated conditions) given the sporadic nature of contamination by pathogens.

This quote from the same WHO document implies that washing is more effective for fresh-harvested produce (e.g. from your garden), and less so for older produce:

> Owing to practicalities, most industry trials of process water sanitizing agents use naturally
> colonized vegetable tissue, which is at the mature biofilm stage and therefore very resistant to
> the effects of washing, even in sanitized water. Commercial washing processes in relation to
> surfaces for fresh-cut produce are typically within a few minutes of chopping, shredding or
> dicing. Such washing occurs before the establishment of the protective extracellular
> polysaccharide, yet the washing process does not remove all of the bacteria (Liao and Cook,
> 2001; Zhang and Farber, 1996; Brocklehurst, 1994; Baranyi, Roberts and McLure, 1993) since
> it fails to address the substantial biofilm element of the attached population.

A lot of data is about food safety protocols on farms (how should they manage their manure/fertilizer, for example), and in the commercial processing which follows, before it's delivered to the consumer.

Comment: However rinsing sprouts can remove dirt, insects and other contaminants before eating them... I prefer my sprouts to be bug free.